# GET Facebook Education Info

Tags: c#, android, facebook, wcf

i am developing android application getting data from facebook.. For data extraction purpose
i am developing a wcf service. In this time i want to get education info of a person
so i am using this code to get  eduction info. but its return only id,, i want to get full details of education.. Please help me.....

```
var facebookClient1 = new FacebookClient(TOKEN);
            var me1 = facebookClient.Get("me?fields=education") as JsonObject;
            inforeturn = me1.ToString();
```

please tell me whats the problem in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Request the **user_education_history** permission.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0

Comment: [Read Step 2: Ask for Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph)  
Example:  
    authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_location", "user_birthday", "user_likes", "user_education_history"));

Comment: i have manually login button.. i am not using facebook button

Comment: You mean the web login button? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.0 Then you just have to add **user_education_history** to your scope

Comment: No i am using Android button and call one function to login in facebook